# $\mathbb Z_N$ Gauge Theory

Tags: mathematical-physics, gauge-theory

I am currently trying to go through some literature on symmetry protected topological phases and gauge theories defined on lattices. I am looking for a mathematically precise reference that discusses $\mathbb Z_N$ gauge theory. Or more generally, a resource that discusses *discrete* gauge theories where the underlying Lie group is a finite, discrete Lie group.

Any recommendations?